# Invalid_State_Err:DOM Exception 11

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am running a apk on android device and this app is created in jquery mobile with phonegap
but the problem is in database
whenever i am using some sqlite queries and using window.opendatabase command than it is giving me exception Invalid_State_Err:DOM Exception 11
I am attaching the code in which insert query and try catch and opendatabse is included
In the given code it is always going in catch after the console.log("query is"+query_ins)
please help me out......

```
try{
                        var query_ins = 'INSERT INTO "users" (name, email, mobile, sex, center, city) VALUES ("'
                            + name_new
                            + '", "'
                            + email_new
                            + '",'
                            + mobile_new
                            + ',"'
                            + sex_new
                            + '","'
                            + center_new 
                            + '","' 
                            + city_new + '")';
                        alert("query is:  "+query_ins);
                        console.log("query is:" +query_ins);



                    var db = window.openDatabase("aakash_db", "2.0","Aakash Database", 200000);
                    alert("1");
                    //db.changeVersion("1.0", "1.1");
                    db.transaction(function(tx) {
                        alert("2");
                        populateDB(tx, query_ins);
                    }, errorCB, successCB);

                    }catch(err){
                        alert("error: "+err.message);
                        console.log("error: "+err.message);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your transaction code like this and try

```
var db = window.openDatabase("aakash_db", "2.0","Aakash Database", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorDB, successDB);
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query_ins);
}
function errorDB(err) {
    alert(err.message)
}
function successDB() {
    //   alert("success!");
}
```